# What happens to the isolated singular points of functions f and g when you multiply the functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, laurent-series

a) Suppose f(z) is analytic and nonzero at a ∈ C, and that g(z) has a non-removable isolated singularity of a given type at a. Show that a
is an isolated singular point of fg and ﬁnd its type.

b) Same question when a is a pole of order N of f.

c) Can anything be asserted about the type of a for fg if f and g have essential singularity at a?

for part a, I do not know how to show that it is still an isolated singular point when you take fg.  To find its type, for an essential singularity I am thinking it remains an essential singularity, but I am not sure how to show that.

how is part b not the same thing asked in a?  Can't a nonremovable singularity be a pole?

For c, I think the answer is no. Would 3 examples where f*g gives each different type suffice to answer this?

Comment: A function like $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $0$. Can you see how to multiply that by another function to "cancel" that singularity?

Comment: Multiply by e^z?

Comment: is that for part c?  so does a not have to be a singularity of fg? @LordSharktheUnknown